# Is the critical point of an embedding of a model of set theory inaccessible in it?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Can we find an elementary embedding $j:M\to N$ with $M,N$ transitive $ZFC$-models, $\kappa$ being the critical point, so that $\kappa$ is not inaccessible in $M$ ? ($\kappa$ is regular in $M$.) I would tend towards "probably yes", but at the moment I don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 9):

To complement Asaf's answer, let me point out that you don't need any large cardinals at all to get embeddings like this; they exist as long as there is an uncountable transitive model of ZFC+"there are no inaccessible cardinals".

If $N$ is such an uncountable model we can get an embedding by taking a countable elementary substructure $X\prec N$ and collapsing it to a transitive $M$. The inverse collapse map gives us the embedding $j\colon M\to N$.
Since the critical point $\kappa$ has the same properties in $M$ as $j(\kappa)$ has in $N$ and $N$ had no inaccessibles, $\kappa$ cannot be inaccessible in $M$.

It is less clear to me what happens if there are no uncountable transitive models of this theory lying around. First of all, there might not be any uncountable transitive models of ZFC at all. And secondly, it doesn't seem impossible that every uncountable transitive model believes that there is an inaccessible (and when you chop it off at that inaccessible the model becomes countable). On the other hand, we are still ok in this second case, at least consistency-wise, since we can pass to $L$ where this cannot happen.

Comment: Right. You can also use a weakly compact cardinal, as noted by Camilo under my answer. Without uncountable transitive models of $\sf ZFC$ you can probably still get this to happen. Implication-wise it's easy, assume there is a largest cardinal for transitive models and collapse it to be countable.

Comment: This is the simplest example to me. Thank you.

Comment: @user35359: I think that the reason you got three very different answers is that it wasn't clear if you want $M$ and $N$ to be set models, or class models or have the same ordinals, or one of them to be a subclass of the other, or if $j$ should be definable internally, or so on and so forth. But at this point I think that we covered most bases, I guess.

Comment: In understand, but I didn't know yet if the most general form of question has an example, although I thought there is probably one, I didn't know how difficult it is, or if restrictions wil make it harder to answer. I also thought about asking : What if $M$ is a model of ZFC minus powerset and $\kappa$ is the largest cardinal in $M$. Anyway, I got some nice answers, so I'm happy.

Comment: @user35359: Yes, you got two very nice answers, and a suggestion to learn Hebrew and master time travel. All in all, not a bad deal. :-D

Comment: @user35359 I've modified my argument a bit to fix a large-ish hole in the proof. The idea is the same but I need a slightly stronger assumption.

Comment: Your edit is an unnecessary complication. If there is an uncountable model of ZFC with an inaccessible, then there is one without. To see this, note that if $M$ is an uncountable transitive model and $\kappa$ is inaccessible in $M$, either $(V_\kappa)^M$ is uncountable, or there an $M$-generic filter for $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\kappa)$. **Edit.** Okay, this requires an argument why $(V_\kappa)^M$ being countable implies that $(V_{\kappa+1})^M$ is countable, but I feel this cannot be false.

Comment: Oh right! I didn't notice the hole  either, thinking of the argument to prove diamond in L with the elementary substructure of $L_{\omega_1}$.  
Couldn't we argue like this: Take the least $\kappa$ with $M\models \, \kappa$ is inaccessible. Then in $V_{\kappa}^M$ ZFC+"there is no inaccessible" holds. The compactness theorem + transitivation should imply there is an uncountable transitive model of ZFC+no inaccessibles (argue with constant symbols $c_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ and sentences $c_{\alpha}\neq c_{\beta}$ for $\alpha <\beta<\omega_1$).

Comment: Ah sure time travel and Hebrew, I will study that next. :D For now, I'm learning Spanish and set theory.

Comment: @user35359 You cannot rely on the compactness theorem to give you wellfounded models for you to transivitize.

Comment: Right. At least we could see by that argument that with reflection, consistency of there is a transitive model of ZFC implies consistency of there is an uncountable transitive model of ZFC without inaccessibles, hence of there is an embedding with critical point which is not inaccessible. But that's not as good.

Comment: Actually, ZFC seems to be equiconsistent with ZFC+there is an enbedding of transitive set models with the critical point not being inaccessible in the first.

Comment: @user35359 Are you sure that's right? Surely you must mean ZFC+there is a transitive model.

Comment: But we can show from the consitency of ZFC the consistency of ZFC+there is a transitive model: Given a finite subset of ZFC, by reflection in any model of ZFC there is a $\theta$ so that $V_{\theta}$ satisfies this subset, so ZFC+(there is transitive M with $M\models$(this subset)) is consistent.

Comment: @user35359 That cannot work, purely on Gödel incompleteness grounds; you basically want to prove that ZFC+Con(ZFC) proves its own consistency. Furtermore, having transitive models for finite fragments of ZFC won't give you a model of the whole thing. You can't use compactness, since the model you would get will almost certainly be ill-founded, so it will have nonstandard ZFC axioms. Thirdly, we know for a fact that there are models of ZFC that contain no transitive models; just look at the least $L_\alpha$ which is a model of ZFC.

Comment: Sure there are such models that contain no transitive models. But saying that there exists a model of ZFC with a transitive element that is a model is different to saying that every model of ZFC contains a model like that. Showing that every finite subset of a theory is consistent is by the compactness theorem enough to show that the theory is consistent. In this case, the theory would be "ZFC+(there exists a transitive model of ZFC)".

Comment: @user35359 I disagree. If you formalize "there is a transitive model of ZFC" by a single assertion then compactness doesn't help you, since the resulting model will have nonstandard axioms and won't believe that your structure models ZFC. If, on the other hand, you formalize it as a schema (and a new constant) you do get a structure modelling ZFC which the overarching model, yielded by compactness, thinks is transitive. But since that model is itself ill-founded, you cannot externalize that structure to get a real transitive thing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the second version with the constant symbol, sorry I wasn't being clear enough on that. Ah but I don't think "that model itself is ill-founded" is an issue, because that's just talking about being externally illfounded, in contrast the axiom of foundation holds inside that model, so just for sake of consistency of the theory, that should be irrelevant. (We might as well take that overarching model to be V. )

Comment: @user35359 Ok, I think I see what you're saying and I agree to an extent. But I think the schema "there is a transitive structure which satisfies each (external) ZFC axiom" is much less interesting and isn't really what we want to talk about with these large cardinals.

Answer (score 6):

No, not necessarily.

Suppose $\kappa$ is measurable in $W$, let $M$ be $W[G]$ the model obtained after forcing with $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,<\kappa)$. If $j\colon W\to W'$ is an ultrapower embedding with critical point $\kappa$, then we can force over $M$ to obtain a model in which $j$ can be extended from $W$ to $M$.

Another important example is the stationary tower forcing, which can produce from a Woodin cardinal in $V$, an embedding [definable in $V[G]$] from $V\to M$, with critical point $\omega_1$.

Somewhere to look for this could be Matt Foreman's chapter in the Handbook "Ideals and Generic Elementary Embeddings". Although admittedly I just learned these facts from my advisor (I don't have notes to distribute, though, sorry).

Comment: What I'm suddenly not sure about is whether $\omega_1$ in the case of the stationary tower forcing is measurable in an inner model. But it is inaccessible in $L$, that's for sure.

Comment: Actually, for your argument above you need only a weakly compact $\kappa$ cardinal, as for any transitive $M$ that is a model of a decent chunk of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $|M|=\kappa\in M$, you can get a embedding $j:M\rightarrow N$ with $crit(j)=\kappa$

Comment: Sure, but this opens to interpretation what do you mean by models. Sets or classes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to read into these 3 (with Camilo's) examples. It'll be fun I guess. About the first example, which forcing do you mean when you say "we can force over M"? Or is that better left as an exercise to figure out?

Comment: @user35359: It's a nontrivial thing, but if you read about generic ultrapowers, this is really the first example. I mean, to have an extension you'd need to get it from $W[G]$ to $W'[H]$ where $H$ is a suitable generic filter, but a generic filter for what? Well, $j(\operatorname{Col}(\omega,<\kappa))$. So you really just need to add this part to $W[G]$ in order to be able and extend the embedding. In the case of this simple example a lot of things really tie neatly together and you get something nice. But it should probably be the first example you'll run into.

Comment: (And if nothing else works, you can always learn Hebrew and then time travel back to roughly two years ago, and sit with us in the course about using large cardinals to force combinatorial properties at small cardinals... :-))

Comment: Ok, I see. Then I'll be able to go from there. Thanks again for the swift response. :)
It seems like there is a science about this kind of forcing.
A course on large cardinals in hebrew, that's  pretty specific. :)

Comment: @user35359: Yes, these sort of arguments are very common after you learn them. They start appearing everywhere, although this is mostly because you suddenly have access to another tool of set theory. :-) And a course in Hebrew about large cardinals is far from specific. We had three of those so far, not counting the one about descriptive set theory which also involved some large cardinals at some point.

Comment: @Asaf I had to chuckle when I realized that a foreign language was the only part of your offer, that seemed uncomfortable to me.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in Asaf's answer, the elementary embedding $j: M\rightarrow N$ does not "live" (that is, is not definable in) $M$.

By contrast, if we have an elementary embedding $j: M\rightarrow N$ which is definable in $M$ (from parameters in $M$), then $crit(j)$ **is** inaccessible, in fact measurable, in $M$: letting $\kappa=crit(j)$, we form the ultrafilter $$\mathcal{U}=\{S\subseteq \kappa: \kappa\in j(S)\},$$ and note that this ultrafilter is $<\kappa$-closed (since $j(\bigcup_{\alpha<\mu}A_\alpha)=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mu} j(A_\alpha)$ for $\mu<\kappa$, since $\kappa=crit(j)$ so $j(\mu)=\mu$); since $\mathcal{U}$ exists in $M$ (since $j$ is definable), we have $\kappa$ is measurable in $M$.

Even if $j$ is not definable in $M$, however, we may form the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ described above; it might not live in $M$, is all that changes. In inner model theory, we are often interested in embeddings which, though maybe not definable over their domain model, nonetheless yield reasonably tame ("amenable") ultrafilters.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: For inaccessibility, we don't need that $N$ is definable in $M$, just that $N\subseteq M$. Right?

Comment: @GME: If $j$ is definable in $M$, then $N$ is definable in $M$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure. But $N\subseteq M$ is weaker than definability of $j$ or $N$ in $M$ in general. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @GME In fact, it should be enough that $M$ and $N$ agree on the power set of $\kappa$.

Comment: @MihaHabič Right! That they agree on the powersets of ordinals less than $\kappa$ would seem to do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I knew this part and I have read about amenable ultrafilters in the context of iterated ultrapowers. I looked in "The Higher Infinite" by Kanamori again and he points out you only need models of ZFC without the powerset axiom to define the M-ultrafilter. (in case M and N have the same powerset of $\kappa$)